# Geometric Sequence with common ratio $1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Does $2,2,2,\dots$ form a geometric sequence?

According to our professor, it is not considered a geometric sequence.
But it follows the rule with $r=1$.

Can anyone please explain to me why or why not is it a geometric sequence? Thanks.

Comment: why didnt you ask ur professor?

Comment: It could as well be a arithmetic sequence with $d=0$

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'll ask our professor on our next meeting.

Answer (score 2):

A sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$ is geometric iff there is $r$ such that $a_n=a_0r^n$ for all $ n \ge 0$.

In your case we have: $a_0=2$. Then $2=a_1=2*r$, hence $r=1$. With this $r$ we indeed have

$2=a_n=a_0r^n$ for all $ n \ge 0$.

Consequence: $(2,2,2,...)$ is geometric and your professor is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) for example.

But it makes a mess of the sum formula:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n ar^i = a\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Comment: That formula works for r≠1.